# hide a sibling on the same level styled-components

Tags: css, sass, styled-components

I have a div that looks like this

```
<div class='normal-select'>....content</div>
<div class='indicators'>....content</div>

<div class='multi-select'>....content</div>
// hide the indicators below
<div class='indicators'>....content</div>
```

Then using `styled-components`/`sass` I want to hide the indicators that are next to the `div` with the `multi-select` class name.

I have tried the following in my `styled-component` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
.multi-select {
  + .indicators {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

can anyone explain what I need to do?

Comment: I don't think that's achievable with just CSS since its all hierarchy based. jQuery could solve this though with $('.multi-select').next('.indicators').addClass('displayNone'); or .css('display', 'none');

Comment: No `+` only `~` ;) [CSS_Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: @GrzegorzT.is it possible, switched from + to ~ but still not working

Comment: @Keith nice solution from GrzegorzT below 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example

```css
.multi-select~.indicators {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='normal-select'>....content a</div>
<div class='indicators'>....content b</div>
<div class='multi-select'>....content c</div>
// hide the indicators below
<div class='indicators'>....content d</div>
```